# Função com CAST e SUBSTRING

Tags: mysql, funções

Está função seria para retorna os dois últimos "955**12**" ou para retornar o número sem os dois últimos dígitos "**955**12".

O valor passado para função pode varia, no mínimo 3 carácter e no máximo 11

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS subInteiro $$
CREATE FUNCTION subInteiro(nCOD INT, nIncio INT, nFim INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE lvl VARCHAR(500); 
 SET lvl = SUBSTRING(CAST(nCOD AS CHAR), nIncio, CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(nCOD AS CHAR)) - nFim ) ;
 RETURN (lvl);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Estou fazendo estes teste**

```
SELECT subInteiro(4518486299,-2,2); # return 47
SELECT subInteiro(201,-2,2); # return 0
```

*No primeiro exemplo era para retorna 99 e no segundo 01*

Answer (score 3):

Para que a mesma função retornar os 2 últimos dígitos ou para retornar o número sem os 2 últimos dígitos é preciso que você não use o LENGTH dentro da função mas sim na chamada dela, segue a função e dois exemplos de uso atendendo as suas necessidades.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `subInteiro` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `subInteiro` (nCOD VARCHAR(500), nIncio INT, nFim INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
BEGIN
  DECLARE lvl VARCHAR(500);

  SELECT SUBSTRING(nCOD, nIncio, nFim) into lvl ;

  RETURN (lvl);
END $$

DELIMITER ;

SELECT subInteiro(4518486299, LENGTH(4518486299)-1, 2)  /*Retorna 99*/
SELECT subInteiro(4518486299, 1, LENGTH(4518486299)-2)  /*retorna 45184862*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido fazendo duas alterações.
A entrada para o valor troquei de **INT** para **BIGINT**
E coloque um **IF** para verificar se é menor ou igual a 3 carácter.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS subInteiro $$
CREATE FUNCTION subInteiro(nCOD BIGINT, nIncio INT, nFim INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE lvl VARCHAR(500); 
    DECLARE ops INT;
    IF nIncio < 0 THEN
    SET ops=1;
    ELSE
        SET ops=2;
    END IF;
    SET lvl = SUBSTRING(CAST(nCOD AS CHAR), nIncio, CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(nCOD AS CHAR)) - IF(LENGTH(nCOD) <= 3, ops, nFim) );
  RETURN (lvl);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```